# Boolean mask within Seaborn Countplot

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I want to apply this Boolean mask

```
csv["country"].value_counts()>5000
```

to this function

```
sns.countplot(y = csv["country"].value_counts()>5000, data = csv)
```

but it rises this error:

```
"Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match)".
```

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
s = csv['country'].value_counts()

s[s > 5000].plot(kind='bar')
```

To use seaborn, you can filter the data using:

```
s = csv['country'].value_counts()
s = s[s > 5000].index.tolist()

sns.countplot(x='country', data=csv.query("country in @s")) # option1
# sns.countplot(x='country', data=csv.loc[df["country"].isin(s))) # option2
```

Comment: this works but I'd like to use the `sns.countplot` function. If I type `sns.countplot(y = s[s>1000], data=csv)` I don't get what I want

Comment: thanks a lot! Once we convert `s` to list, is there a way to set `data` = to s without having to use the `csv.query`? That would be something like `sns.countplot(y='country', data=s)`

Comment: you need to filter the data, you can try option 2 which uses `.loc` instead to filter the data.

Comment: we can rewrite also option 2 in this way `sns.countplot(y='country', data=csv[csv["country"].isin(s)])` since we don't need  `.loc` to access to the columns